# Generate Dropbox Direct Download Link (Old Method No More Working)

Tags: download, dropbox, file-sharing

Following is the process i generate direct download links for files uploaded in Dropbox.

By direct link i mean which directly start download from browser or can use programmatically to download the files directly without any landing page.

I generate and copy the link provided by Dropbox. ex:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hriinb9w3a2107m/iPad%20intro.pdf?dl=0
```

then replace the "www.dropbox.com" with "dl.dropboxusercontent.com" which become:

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/hriinb9w3a2107m/iPad%20intro.pdf
```

and it works as direct link. It was working even last month when i last tried.

But when i am trying now, it looks like Dropbox change the method to create the copy/share link. It producing links like following:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/9mto1g6dxiucx1j9sfiw5/ChilkatDotNet45_x64.7z?rlkey=hpxwfllpz5gx3x3gesomoqp18&dl=0
```

And i can seems to find any way to change it to direct download link..

that's why i came here for some help!

best regards

Comment: Refer to this help article for information on modifying Dropbox shared links for direct access: https://help.dropbox.com/share/force-download

Comment: @Greg, please check the links type on that page you have mentioned, it's also and old document, new links only generate one time download link that doesn't work next time :(

Comment: While that help article is older and shows a "/s/" as an example, the `dl` and `raw` parameters it shows should also work on "/scl/fi/" links now. Also, the URLs returned on the redirects should only be used once, but you can use the original links with the modified`dl` or `raw` parameters repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change "&dl=0" to "&dl=**1**" as writen here:
https://help.dropbox.com/share/force-download

Answer (score 0):

you can now do one thing, just make the changes in "www.dropbox.com" only and leave the rest link as it is, it will work as you want.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).